# flipping a coin 100 times and getting at least 3 heads

Tags: probability

I am learning about probability and I am having a difficult time computing the correct answer to this question. what is the probability of getting at least 3 heads if I flip a coin 100 times.

Comment: You get at least three if you don't get $0, 1$ or $2$. The chance of $0$ is $(\frac 12)^{100}$.  Can you do the binomial to get the chance of $1$ or $2$?

Answer (score 4):

Getting at least $3$ heads. This means you want to find the probability of getting *exactly* 3 heads or (so add the probability) getting *exactly* 4 heads or getting *exactly* 5 heads or ..... Do you see how this is getting long? For such long calculations, you probably want to calculate the probably of the OPPOSITE. Because if $A$ is an event we want to have happen (like getting $3$ or more heads), the probability of $A$ happening is $P(A)$. But the probability if $A$ NOT happening is $P(A^C)$. We have a nifty relation between them: $P(A^C)=1-P(A)$. Therefore, $P(A)=1-P(A^C)$.

So I'll leave you with this hint:

HINT: What is the opposite of getting $3$ *heads or more*? What is the probability of this event? Then using the first paragraph, find the probability of getting $3$ or more heads.